# How to perform row wise OR operation on a 2D numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array.

```
[[1, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 1]]
```

I want to perform rowise OR operation on it so that the resulting array looks like this:

`[1, 0, 1]`

Is there a straight forward way for doing this without implementing loops ?
I will be very grateful if someone could suggest something. Thanks

Comment: `b = a[0,:]|a[1,:]|a[2,:] where a is the numpy array`. This works pretty well. I am looking for something more precise and compact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd prefer to stick with bitwise or (the [`|` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations) in Python is a bitwise or, whereas the [`or` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#or) is the boolean or), you can use [`np.bitwise_or()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_or.html). However, this only takes two arrays as input, so you can use Numpy's [`reduce()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html) capabilities to combine all the subarrays in the array.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1]])
>>> np.bitwise_or.reduce(a, 0)
array([1, 0, 1])
```

I like how explicit this is, but the `a.any()` solution is common enough to not raise any eyebrows. The first argument for `reduce` is of course the `array` and the second is the `axis` you're reducing along. So you could also do it column-wise, if you preferred, or any other axis for that matter.

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 1]])
>>> np.bitwise_or.reduce(a, 1)
array([1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: hey thanks, @Alexander Reynolds, this is exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Beat me to this answer by 30 seconds.  although I would use `np.bitwise_or.reduce(a, 0)` to be that much more explicit.

Comment: @DanielF I agree, I'll add that in. Thanks!

Comment: @deepayandas if my solution was what you were looking for, could you accept my answer? Otherwise if you're interested in any expansions I could elaborate.

Comment: @deepayandas great, I just added links to the documentation for all the relevant functions too.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this by calling [`any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) to generate a boolean mask and then cast to `int` to convert the `True` and `False` to `1` and `0` respectively:

```
In[193]:
a.any(0).astype(int)

Out[193]: array([1, 0, 1])
```

The first param to `any` is the axis arg, here we can see the differences between axis 0 and 1:

```
In[194]:
a.any(0)

Out[194]: array([ True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In[195]:
a.any(1)

Out[195]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```